# How does a boogie board/LCD writing tablet/ChLCD reset actually work?

Tags: lcd, physics, physical-design

there are those boogie boards, which essentially are just special LCD screens: ChLCD screens.
which work by reflecting light on the places where it is activated.
in a boogie board, the pressure causes the molecules to spin and enter the reflective/coloured state.

the reset however, is done electrically.
I have seen many people take those boards apart and show it is electrically, but noone really actually showed or explained how the reset itself works.

**So how does the electrically powered reset actually work?
and what kind of things does such a display react to other than pressure, and how?**

for example is it?:

- voltage touching the screen
- static electricity/capacitance
- magnetism
- electromagnetism/induction
- heat
- pressure(for example piezo)
- something else

I wonder this, since I wonder if it might be possible and doable to frankenstein alter one of those boards/displays, to instead of using pressure from a user, to controll it electrically, by for example adding a special layer or thin copper wires or such.

Comment: I have never heard of a "boogie board" in this context; what does it refer to? an  LCD writing tablet uses a touchscreen and full electrical control of its screen, not anythiing pressure-related.

Comment: @Hearth There are tablets the use direct pressure to change the LCD state, and then electrical pulse to clear the screen. No touchscreens or anything fancy involved. They are easy to get from usual sources, chain stores like Walmart probably carry them too. May be worth checking out, they are clever engineering.

Comment: what is preventing from answering most of your questions experimentally?

Comment: not having proper testing/experimenting equipment, plus my manual accuracy not always being as accurate as hoped, especially soldering and such, this might result in me destroying the test materials or generating a false negative.
also since I do not own a broken chlcd writing pad, and if I would happen to destroy a fully working one then I wouldn't really like that since I would see it as unneccesary destruction, however I know many people have broken one, and since it is such old technology it might be realistic someone has already tried this, or that someone knows the full science behindit